# Defining windows to find multiple slopes

Tags: matlab, math

I need to define several windows for an experimental plot for which slopes can be found. For example, x runs from 0 to 400. I want to find the derivative of each 50x (i.e. 0 to 50, 50 to 100 & so on), and then average all derivatives (8 derivatives in this example). Thanks for any helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a vector `y` of measurements and want to compute the derivative by taking the difference between entry 1 and 50, 51 and 100, and so on, you could do the following:

```
% generate a signal
x=1:400;
y = x.^2;
nSamples = length(y);

% define number of segments and window size
N = 8;      
Winsize = ceil(nSamples/N);

% preallocate the vector of slopes and compute the slopes
slopes = zeros(1,N);
for ii=1:N
    slopes(ii) = (y(min(nSamples,Winsize*ii))-y(1+Winsize*(ii-1)))/(x(min(nSamples,Winsize*ii))-x(1+Winsize*(ii-1)));
end

% take the average slope value
Averageslope = mean(slopes);
```

However, since you are using matlab anyway you could also just take the average derivative of the vector, which should yield a much more accurate average when dealing with noisy data:

```
% generate a signal
x=1:400;
y = x.^2;
slope = mean(diff(y)/diff(x));
```